# How to generate a shell script from org file

Tags: org-export

I would like to develop a shell script in org mode, but have no idea as to how to generate the actual script from the file.

Is there some package which will do a conversion?

Comment: `C-h f org-babel-tangle` will write the contents of a source block to a file. But what kind of conversion are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package that manages org source blocks is called org-babel. Much of its functionality is in [block header arguments](https://org-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/header-args/) that modify how the block behaves.

This will get you started:

```
#+begin_src shell :shebang #!/bin/bash :mkdirp yes :tangle ~/test/hello.sh    
  echo "Hello, world!"
#+end_src
```

You will then need to call `org-babel-tangle` to write to the file.

Comment: Many thanks, simpler than I thought.  Just that under FreeBSD it would be #!/bin/sh for any FreeBSD users who might be looking for such a solution.

Comment: Just wondered if anyone could point me to some examples of a well documented shell script in org mode so that I could get a better understanding of the capabilities of org-babel...

Comment: The script itself makes no difference: you can replace the  `echo "Hello, world" trivial script above with whatever script you want (but writing such a script is off-topic for this site). Detailied docs for the Babel shell implementation can be found [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-shell.html).